# How to deal with a slow consumer in traditional Java NIO?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, nio, nonblocking

So, I've been brushing up my understanding of traditional Java non-blocking API. I'm a bit confused with a few aspects of the API that seem to force me to handle backpressure manually.

For example, the documentation on [WritableByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) says the following:

> Unless otherwise specified, a write operation will return only after
> writing all of the requested bytes. Some types of channels,
> depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or
> possibly none at all. A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for
> example, cannot write any more bytes than are free in the socket's
> output buffer.

Now, consider this example taken from Ron Hitchens book: [Java NIO](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-nio/0596002882/).

In the piece of code below, Ron is trying to demonstrate how we could implement an echo response in a non-blocking socket application (for context here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/edalorzo/39619f1ba09b4e05a7c57ba6e72fd0d9) with the full example).

```
//Use the same byte buffer for all channels. A single thread is
//servicing all the channels, so no danger of concurrent access.
private ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);

protected void readDataFromSocket(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
    var channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    buffer.clear(); //empty buffer

    int count;
    while((count = channel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        buffer.flip(); //make buffer readable

        //Send data; don't assume it goes all at once
        while(buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            channel.write(buffer);
        }

        //WARNING: the above loop is evil. Because
        //it's writing back to the same nonblocking
        //channel it read the data from, this code
        //can potentially spin in a busy loop. In real life
        //you'd do something more useful than this.

        buffer.clear(); //Empty buffer
    }

    if(count < 0) {
        //Close channel on EOF, invalidates the key
        channel.close();
    }
}
```

My confusion is on the while loop writing into output channel stream:

```
//Send data; don't assume it goes all at once
while(buffer.hasRemaining()) {
   channel.write(buffer);
}
```

It really confuses me how NIO is helping me here. Certainly the code may not be blocking as per the description of the `WriteableByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer)`, because if the output channel cannot accept any more bytes because its buffer is full, this write operation does not block, it just writes nothing, returns, and the buffer remains unchanged. But --at least in this example-- there is no easy way to use the current thread in something more useful while we wait for the client to process those bytes. For all that matter, if I only had one thread, the other requests would be piling up in the selector while this while loop wastes precious cpu cycles “waiting” for the client buffer to open some space. There is no obvious way to register for readiness in the output channel. Or is there?

So, assuming that instead of an echo server I was trying to implement a response that needed to send a big number of bytes back to the client (e.g. a file download), and assuming that the client has a very low bandwidth or the output buffer is really small compared to the server buffer, the sending of this file could take a long time. It seems as if we need to use our precious cpu cycles attending other clients while our slow client is chewing our file download bytes.

If we have readiness in the input channel, but not on the output channel, it seems this thread could be using precious CPU cycles for nothing. It is not blocked, but it is as if it were since the thread is useless for undetermined periods of time doing insignificant CPU-bound work.

To deal with this, Hitchens' solution is to move this code to a new thread --which just moves the problem to another place--. Then I wonder, if we had to open a thread every time we need to process a long running request, how is Java NIO better than regular IO when it comes to processing this sort of requests?

It is not yet clear to me how I could use traditional Java NIO to deal with these scenarios. It is as if the promise of doing more with less resources would be broken in a case like this. What if I were implementing an HTTP server and I cannot know how long it would take to service a response to the client?

It appears as if this example is deeply flawed and a good design of the solution should consider listening for readiness on the output channel as well, e.g.:

```
registerChannel(selector, channel, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

But how would that solution look like? I’ve been trying to come up with that solution, but I don’t know how to achieve it appropriately.

I'm not looking for other frameworks like Netty, my intention is to understand the core Java APIs. I appreciate any insights anyone could share, any ideas on what is the proper way to deal with this back pressure scenario just using traditional Java NIO.

Answer (score 1):

NIO's non-blocking mode enables a thread to request reading data from a channel, and only get what is currently available, or nothing at all, if no data is currently available. Rather than remain blocked until data becomes available for reading, the thread can go on with something else.

The same is true for non-blocking writing. A thread can request that some data be written to a channel, but not wait for it to be fully written. The thread can then go on and do something else in the meantime.

What threads spend their idle time on when not blocked in IO calls, is usually performing IO on other channels in the meantime. That is, a single thread can now manage multiple channels of input and output.

So I think you need to rely on the design of the solution by using a design pattern for handling this issue, maybe **Task or Strategy design pattern ** are good candidates and according to the framework or the application you are using you can decide the solution.

But in most cases you don't need to implement it your self as it's already implemented in Tomcat, Jetty etc.

Reference : [Non blocking IO](https://www.hellsoft.se/non-blocking-io/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A followup question. If your thread is writing, in traditional Java NIO, your buffer may not be fully consumed because the output buffer is full. Say you put your thread to do something else. What do you do with pending data pending to be send and how do you know when the output buffer is ready for more? It seems to me that one must also register for the output channel readiness. It is just that I never see such pattern in examples of traditional Java NIO.

Comment: I think there is no output buffer it's a stream and once you write to the channel it appends to the stream, the problem will be in the memory consumption!

Comment: Are you certain of that? How would it work if the network bandwidth of the server and the are quite different? The TCP connection most certainly must buffer bytes. The quote I shared in the question explicitly mentions the output buffer. The [documentation of SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) and [ServerSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html) explicitly mention the send and receive buffers as configurable options.

Comment: Actually i read that from the java doc for the
        Channels.newChannel(OutputStream out)

So it will differ from one Channel type to another

Comment: See this and tell me if I understand something wrong
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/Channels.html